# Split a variable into an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get a PHP script to split a list of numbers separated by a comma into an array, which i can then loop through and execute a command for each number in the list.

So what i really want to achieve is this;

```
$numbers = "2564521,5451254"
$data = array($numbers)
```

However this will not work with an array.

This is what i have so far;

```
$data = array(2564521,5451254);

//Our 'stepping' variable
$g = 0;

//Our rowcount
$rowcount = 0;

echo "<table cellspacing='0'>\r";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($data); ) {

        $rowcount++;
        echo "    <tr>\r"; //New row

        $g = $i + 3; //Set our nested limit
        for( ; $i<$g; $i++) { //nested for loop

            if (!isset($data[$i])) { //Allow us to break on incomplete rows
                break;
            }

            echo "        <td style='border: 1px #000 solid;'>\r"; //Out put a cell
            echo "         Number: $data[$i]</p>\r";
            echo "        </td>\r";
            echo "$data[$i]</p>\r";

            $tonumbers = "$data[$i]";

//Execute command for each number


        }

        echo "    </tr> \r"; //End New Row
    }

echo "</table>\r";?>

I would appreciate any help, thanks!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your code.  Let me see if this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php

$testdata = "123123123123,34234804982";

$data = explode(",", $testdata);

foreach($data as $number) {
    echo $number . '|';
}

?>
```

Comment: I am glad.  Please mark this as a accepted answer.  It's the check-mark next to the up arrow.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like PHP, if so you can do

```
$data = explode(",", $numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks, although i did try that and all i got was the first number and only the first digit of the second number, I'm not sure why though?

Comment: If you have a string `$numbers = "2564521,5451254"`, then it should split those numbers into an array with explode. What is the data you are working with?